# How to iterate different control types (Checkbox and TextBox) combined and at the same time in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am working on a program that checks if a checkbox is checked. Then using its text property to proces further stuff.
I have added numericUpDown boxes to give the user the possibility to enter own values. Until now I am iterating all checkboxes and check if some of them are checked. But now I want to Iterate the checkboxes and if one of them is checked, I want to get the Number in the numericUpDown Box beneath the checked checkbox.

[image]

What is the best approach to Iterate the Checkboxes and the numericUpDown Boxes at once?
Should I group them? Or put them into an extra panel?

Here is how I iterate the checkboxes until now:

```
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if ((c is CheckBox) && ((CheckBox)c).Checked)
        {
        //Do some stuff
        }
    }
```

I am sorry for my bad english and hope someone can help. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, group the CheckBox and NumericUpDown in a UserControl.  Now things are naturally related.

Comment: What Lars said.  Or, ditch this and use MVVM, where things like this become trivial tasks.

Comment: Note that if you have only one checkbox checked at a time, then it's better to use radiobuttons

Comment: There are many checkboxes checked at the same time.

Comment: @SardarAgabejli you say in question *I am iterating all checkboxes and check if one if them is checked*

Comment: I am sorry, then I have to say: "And check if some of them are checked".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lars suggested, creating user control which groups checkbox and numericUpDown together is a good idea:

```
public partial class ToggleNumericControl : UserControl
{
    public ToggleNumericControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get { return checkBox.Text;  }
        set { checkBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public bool Checked
    {
        get { return checkBox.Checked;  }
        set { checkBox.Checked = value; }
    }

    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return numericUpDown.Value; }
        set { numericUpDown.Value = Value; }
    }
}
```

You can, of course, implement additional functionality here. E.g. disabling numericUpDown when the checkbox is unchecked.

Place such controls to you form, and then you can select checked values this way:

```
var selectedValues = from tn in panel1.Controls.OfType<ToggleNumericControl>()
                     where tn.Checked
                     select tn.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I have an other question. As you can see on the screenshot the checkBoxes have different names. Is there a way to change the checkBox Text when its already bind to a user control? I mean, is there a Text property where I can set the text manualy? Or do I have to do this programaticaly? Thank you!

Comment: @SardarAgabejli yes, user control has virtual property `Text` you can override it so that it will write and read value of checkbox text. But you should think about space for this text - it either should be fixed width or you should make it resizeable (e.g. by placing both controls to table layout panel)